# The package name of your Instant App APKs should be the same as your app's package name

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to upload my instant app t play store. I see the below error which uploading instant app apk zip:
The package name of your Instant App APKs should be the same as your app's package name

My build.gradles for respective features as below:

Installed apk (build.gradle) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "arith.math.arithapk"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
implementation project(':arithbase')
implementation project(":arithmaticsumfeature")
 }
```

base (build.gradle):

```
  //apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
baseFeature = true
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
      }

  dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
 core:3.0.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
feature project(":arithmaticsumfeature")
api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   application project(':arithapk')
}
```

Feature(build.gradle):

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

      android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"


defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
  }

   dependencies {
api project(':arithbase')
    }
```

Instant app (build.gradle):

```
          apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

  dependencies {
implementation project(':arithbase')
implementation project(":arithmaticsumfeature")
   }
```

Can any one help me in resolving this issue. ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you haven't visit the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/structure.html), try to do so. There is this section(Structure of an instant app with multiple features) that describe what the structure of the instant app composed of as well as the way to reduce the size of the app to optimize the code. For further examples, you can visit this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540528/google-play-console-package-name-of-your-instant-app-apks-should-be-the-same-as) which got the same error as you have.

Comment: updated base(build.gradle)

Answer (score 0):

updated base (build.gradle) with application project(':arithapk') and issue is  fixed

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this issue by setting the correct package names in the Android Manifest of each module, following this rules:

Base Module: The Base module package name needs to be assigned with the same value you set for the applicationID in the build.gradle file from the Application module, in this case "arith.math.arithapk".

Application Module: The Application module package name needs to be one level bellow the applicationID set in build.gradle. If your Base module package name is "arith.math.arithapk" you can set the app module package name to "arith.math.arithapk.app" or "arith.math.arithapk.application".

Instant App Module: You don't need to set any package name to this module, since it doesn't have a manifest.

Feature Module: The package names for the feature modules should be assigned one level bellow the base module package name, like "arith.math.arithapk.feature"